# Windows > Vagrant > nodejs can't see local packages

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, vagrant

I try to setup my environment on my laptop with windows 10. I need linux anvironment but windows is more comfortable for me. Thats why I deside to use Vagrant with Ubuntu.

So I have following:

- Windows 10 - main OS
- Vagrant 1.9.2
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux
  3.13.0-110-generic x86_64) - virtual OS
- node 6.10.0
- npm 3.10.10

**[Here is my vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/Webbrother/94e91029d3638d07192034d7ae67f898)**

**[Here is my shell for my virtual box](https://gist.github.com/Webbrother/d99c9ad53ce9c6071e17fb4e5969d79d)**

## The problem:

After all installations I do `npm i` and it looks like everithing is OK.

**But** when I run my scripts which uses some local packages - nodejs says:

`sh: 1: <local-package>: not found`

it can be everithing:

`sh: 1: cpy: not found`

`sh: 1: npm-run-all: not found`

`sh: 1: rimraf: not found` etc...

I tried a lot of different versions of ubuntu (ubuntu/trusty64, ubuntu/xenial64), nodejs (4.x.x, 6.x.x, 7.x.x, latest), npm (2.x.x, 3.x.x, 4.x.x, latest) and everytime I got the same problem with local npm packages.

Any ideas how to solve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you trying to execute binaries from filesystem that is not *nix compatible and doesn't supports files to be marked executable with `chmod +x`.

There is some potential workarounds you can try to fix this issues, but all of them has some cons. See [article](http://ryansechrest.com/2014/04/unable-set-permissions-within-shared-folder-using-vagrant-virtualbox/) by Ryan Sechrest about this exact problem.

So, basicaly you should find a way to remount shared folders with executable flag for all files by default or setup some sort of sync between *nix compatible fs and shared folder.